# What is the name of this kind of joint?

Tags: joinery, hardware-identification

I know this is a woodworking Q&A, but since googling to the best of my keywording skills didn't work, I'm trying my luck here.

I'm trying to build a home office desk for myself, with a metal frame, but I'd like it not to be a one big welded piece of frame. I found this dinner table in a store that had this clever joinery, which could "easily" solve my problems.

Anyone knows what it's called?

[image: metal joint]

Comment: They're also sometimes referred to simply as "table leg brackets", and if you're ever making a whole table in wood they are easily made from wood only. The all-wood ones are usually of the form seen in Matt's Answer [here](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2821/attaching-legs-to-a-table).

Comment: One other thing to check is about your wooden top, is it solid wood (including glued-together panels) or a manmade board such as MDF, plywood or particleboard/chipboard? If you'll be using one of the latter there are no further complications, but if your top is solid wood you will need to attach it to allow for seasonal expansion and contraction.

Answer (score 2):

Try googling "surface mount table leg corner bracket". You'll get lots of wood ones, but the principle extends to metal if you screw/tap stuff together.